# Need help dockerize an apt-cacher-ng service

Tags: docker, ubuntu, debian

I'm following

**Dockerize an apt-cacher-ng service**
https://docs.docker.com/engine/examples/apt-cacher-ng/

but failed to get it up and running.

I've successfully followed to

> To see the logfiles that are tailed in the default command, you can use:
>
> ```
> $ docker logs -f test_apt_cacher_ng
> ```

and I get

```
$ docker logs -f test_apt_cacher_ng
WARNING: No configuration was read from file:sfnet_mirrors
Starting apt-cacher-ng: apt-cacher-ng.
```

But that's as far as I can go and can't go any further. 
I think my step:

```
$ docker run -d -p 3142:3142 --name test_apt_cacher_ng eg_apt_cacher_ng
```

does not give me an `apt_cacher_ng` at port `3142`, because:

```
$ ip a s | grep 'docker0$'
    inet 172.17.0.1/16 brd 172.17.255.255 scope global docker0

$ nc -z 172.17.0.1 3142 | wc        
      0       0       0

$ lsof -i :3142 | wc
      0       0       0
```

What else can I check to make sure I've got a dockerized apt-cacher-ng service, and it is also up and running?

Comment: What is the result of the `docker ls`, doe your container run correctly?

Comment: Duplicate for the people that are using `apt-cacher` (without NG): https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/684123/unable-to-use-apt-cacher/684131

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Networking is more complicated, because container is running in own network namespace. See listenings:

```
$ netstat -tanp  | grep 3142
tcp        0      0 172.17.0.1:39182        172.17.0.1:3142         TIME_WAIT   -
tcp6       0      0 :::3142                 :::*                    LISTEN      46336/docker-proxy
```

The best option will be to check from host OS (apt-cacher-ng is exposed on all interfaces on the port 3142) with `curl`:

```
$ curl http://127.0.0.1:3142
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
   <head>
      <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=iso-8859-1" />
      <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=8" />
      <meta name="MSSmartTagsPreventParsing" content="true" />
      <title>Not Found or APT Reconfiguration required</title>
      <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/style.css" />
   </head>
...
```

Comment: Thanks a lot Jan for the info on how to confirm whether my apt-cacher-ng service is up and running! I made it works now.