# How to fix dockerized apt-cacher-ng service only listen to IPv6

Tags: docker, ubuntu, debian

Following up on [Need help dockerize an apt-cacher-ng service](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55155332/), one of the problem is, although my apt-cacher-ng service is up and running, but it is only listening to IPv6:

```
$ netstat -tanp  | grep 3142
(Not all processes could be identified, non-owned process info
 will not be shown, you would have to be root to see it all.)
tcp6       0      0 :::3142                 :::*                    LISTEN      -
```

Again, I'm following

**Dockerize an apt-cacher-ng service**
https://docs.docker.com/engine/examples/apt-cacher-ng/

Is something missing from that doc?
(The only thing I changed from the doc is to replace the "FROM" base from `ubuntu` to `debian:sid`)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually, your service is listening also on IPv4 interfaces. IPv6 listening in the `netstat` output is a problem of combination `netstat` and `docker-proxy`. See more details in the question [Make docker use IPv4 for port binding](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29957143/make-docker-use-ipv4-for-port-binding)